# F#: For MathNet Numerics the value or constructor matrix is not defined

Tags: .net, matrix, f#, mathnet-numerics

I'm trying to learn F#, and to create a matrix I follow the instructions from here: http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

```
module Gew.M
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra


let matrix1 =   matrix [[1.0; 2.0]; [1.0; 3.0]]
let matrix2 =  matrix [[1.0; -2.0]; [0.5; 3.0]]
let matrix12 = matrix1 * matrix2
```

Then I get this error: the value or constructor matrix is not defined

Comment: Are you referencing `MathNet.Numerics.FSharp` package as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read carefully:

> Even though the core of Math.NET Numerics is written in C#, it aims to
>   support F# just as well. In order to achieve this we recommend to
>   reference the MathNet.Numerics.FSharp package in addition to
>   MathNet.Numerics, which adds a few modules to make it more idiomatic
>   and includes arbitrary precision types (BigInteger, BigRational).

So, you have to add a reference to **MathNet.Numerics.FSharp**

Example:

```
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

let matrix1 =   matrix [[1.0; 2.0]; [1.0; 3.0]]
let matrix2 =  matrix [[1.0; -2.0]; [0.5; 3.0]]
let matrix12 = matrix1 * matrix2

matrix12 |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
DenseMatrix 2x2-Double
  2  4
2.5  7
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6NSti7